# Copy whole directory but exclude all folders and subfolders with certain name

Tags: bash, unix, cp

I'm not allowed to use rsync on the cluster I'm working on so I need to use cp. I want to copy a large directory including all files and subfolders etc. but without any folders that have the name "outdir".
I tried  `cp -r -v ./!(outdir) ../target-directory/`
but it still copies all folders and contents in deeper directories with the name outdir. It only included the outdir folders in the highest directory.

I also tried `cp -r ./*/!(outdir) ../target-directory/` but that one copied all files into the folder without keeping any hirarchy or folders etc.

I also tried certain find commands but it didn't work, but maybe I was just doing something stupid. I'm a beginner with bash so if you could explain your answer and what the flags etc. do that would really be helpfull, I've been trying forever now, on what I think shouldn't be that hard to do.

Comment: Did you execute `shopt -s extglob` in advance?

Comment: Can your `outdir` directories appear at any level in the hierarchy? If so then you should install your own copy of rsync, IMO.

Comment: yes they can appear at various levels and yes, I did shopt -s extglob

Comment: any link/suggestion on how to install my own copy?

Comment: What OS will run the `rsync` command?

Comment: it's a big supercomputer of a university that's running Scientific Linux 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `cp`, you can use `tar` with option `--exclude` to control what you want copied or not.

The full command is:

```
tar --exclude="outdir" -cvpf - . | (cd TARGET_DIRECTORY; tar -xpf -)
```

- So any path that contains the "outdir" pattern will be excluded.
- Without the `--exclude` option, it will copy the entire structure of your current directory under TARGET_DIRECTORY.
- You can replace the `.` in the first tar by your desired source directory.

Comment: does this also work for excluding file names? So if I put "filename" instead of "outdir" would all files called "filename" be ignored in the copy process?

Comment: Yes it would.  Anything that matches the pattern defined in `--exclude``.